# Transparent Iframe background not validating in IE

Tags: html, iframe

I am using an "emailmeform" in an iframe for a contacts page and the background won't go transparent. I have added `allowtransparency="true"` to the iframe and it's doing nothing.

I know I should add  `<body style="background:transparent">` into the source to make this normally work but I have the exact same iframe on another page and the transparency works, but trying it on this new page with the same code for some reason doesn't work.

Here's the bog standard iframe code, I just can't see what's going wrong.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="600" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="border:none" src="http://www.emailmeform.com/builder/embed/Mnc79QelZ4v8r">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`allowtransparency` is NOT in `<iframe>` specification, thus it is doing nothing. This keyword support is removed since IE9.

`background: transparent` is doing nothing either. It depends on how browser renders this transparency. In short, avoid using transparent background.

> The `transparent` keyword maps to `rgb(0,0,0)`.

*Sidenote:* However, similar parameter exists in [XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Attribute/iframe.transparent), but this does not apply to your case.

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color